# Nestjs JwtStrategy access to context

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I have a `UseGuard` in my WebSocket. Actually, this guard is a `JwtAuthGuard` that extends `AuthGuard('jwt')`. The `JwtAuthGuard` has a Strategy class called `JwtStrategy`. In this class, I have a `validate` method. In HTTP-based requests I return **payload** in this method. Then nestjs attach the payload to the `req`. Here is my Strategy class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authConfigService: AuthConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: authConfigService.JWT_SECRET,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

I want to have access to **context**  within `validate` method in order to attach the payload to the WebSocket's body (or anything that I can have access to the payload). Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `context`? What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel the same thing that we can do in the guards `canActivate` method that you can have access to the Execution context. For your second question, I want to attach the payload to something related to WS, then I can access to the payload in my web socket service. (The same thing that nestjs does for HTTP.  In this case it sets the payload to the `req`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make any modifications to your strategy class. Instead, you should modify your `JwtAuthGuard`'s `getRequest` method (if you don't have one then you should make one) that returns an object that has a `headers` proeprty that is an object with a `authorization` property that is a string. Something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ws = context.switchToWs().getClient(); // possibly `getData()` instead.
    return {
      headers: {
        authorization: valueFromWs(ws),
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also make this work across different context types by using an `if/else` or a `switch` statement and returning the correct object based on the `contextType` from `context.getType()`. Whatever is returned from this `getRequest` method is where passport will end up attaching the `user` property, so it may make sense to return the entire client *with* these extra values.

Comment: Thank you. As I knew, we determine about attaching the payload in the Strategy class's `validate` method that we return payload. But I can test it. And one more question, how can I access this user property in WS service?

Comment: The thing that I've done is to do the similar thing in `canActivate` method. I get the token from WS and attach it to HTTP's header. So nestjs behave the request like an HTTP request. But didn't know how to do it in Strategy (in validate method)

Comment: As I mentioned, whatever you return from `getRequest` is the object that Passport attaches the user to. If you want that to be on the WS Client, then you need to get an object off of the `client` and return it with the properties mentioned. Then passport will attach the user back to this object. You really shouldn't be worrying about doing anything in the strategy other than validating the request

Comment: Thank you. Is it exist in the nestjs documentation? Because I didn't see it anywhere

Comment: Under the [GraphQL](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object) section